# google analytic prolem with event and customvar

Tags: magento, google-analytics

i have  problem with google analytic .

Here is my code :

```
<script>
   function trackRegister()
  {
      if(dataForm.validator.validate()) {
        _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar",4,"Type","Besogende-med-Konto",1]);  
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ActivateVisitorProfileTracking', 'ActivateVisitorProfileTracking']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Konto-oprettet', 'Engage', 'Personlig-Konto-Oprettet']);         
      }

  }
```

i call trackRegister function when click submit button then page will be redirect to result page ,but i only receive ActivateVisitorProfileTracking event on google analytic report. But i don't know why .Anyone can help me? thank for any help :D

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of how you are calling it, it sounds like maybe your page is being redirected before your 2nd _trackEvent call has a chance to execute.  Try wrapping your redirect in a setTimeout , or wrapping your GA code with code to detect status of the GA calls and only redirect when it returns complete